# Hudson CI: able to run more than 2 concurrent builds?

Tags: hudson

In Hudson CI, I noticed that when I try to run multiple builds at same time, it caps out at 2 concurrent builds. I want to allow more. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the Hudson main configuration window and increase the number of Executors there.

Manage Hudson -> Configure System

There is a field called # of executors.  You can increase that the the number of concurrent builds (not similar) you want to run at any given time.